# How to generate a random char in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a column in my table in which I can insert M or F, according to the user's gender (Male or Female).

I need to generate this column randomly.

This column type is VARCHAR2(1).

I think I should use something like :

```
TRUNC(dbms_random.value(X,X))
```

But I dont know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `dbms_random.value` returns a value >= 0 and < 1, I'd just use something like this assuming you want an equal probability of getting an M or an F.  If you want to produce a skewed distribution, adjust the 0.5 value to whatever you'd like

```
case when dbms_random.value < 0.5
     then 'M'
     else 'F'
 end
```